# Replace the array values with html image tag in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have here an array below:

```
<?php
print_r( $result ); 
?>
```

If I am going to execute the code above, it resulted below:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [uploaded_by] => 1
        [image_url] => http://localhost/dir/img_2.jpg
        [work_description] => test
        [date_added] => 2017-08-03 02:12:38
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [uploaded_by] => 1
        [image_url] => http://localhost/dir/img_4.jpg
        [work_description] => test
        [date_added] => 2017-08-03 02:13:04
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [uploaded_by] => 1
        [image_url] => http://localhost/dir/img_2.jpg
        [work_description] => test
        [date_added] => 2017-08-03 02:46:28
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [uploaded_by] => 1
        [image_url] => http://localhost/dir/img_2.jpg
        [work_description] => sdfsdf
        [date_added] => 2017-08-03 02:46:34
    )
)
```

Now, from the `$result` array I wanted to change the values of all `image_url` 
 **programmatically** using php into an image in html.

example:

`http://localhost/dir/img_2.jpg` will become

`<img src="http://localhost/dir/img_2.jpg"/>`

Those values must be changed if I am going to execute the code.

Does anybody know?

Comment: what do you want to get after the change ? are you looking for `<img src="http://localhost/dir/img_2.jpg"/>` ? if yes this is already there. Pls, let us know clearly.

Comment: okay. will modify my question. Hope you can understand.

Comment: What is the problem? Loop over array and concatenate strings. Provide what you have already tried.

Comment: this has been solved already.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put it in a `foreach` and modify only the part what you want:

```
foreach($result as $key => $value) {
    $result[$key]['image_url'] = '<img src="'.$value['image_url'].'"/>';
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Although, the `image_url` is an array and not an object. Therefore, it must be  `$result[$key]['image_url'] = '<img src="'.$value['image_url'].'"/>';` Just edit though for future reference. thanks

Comment: Also with the `$value->image_url` .. Make it an array.. thanks. The person who downvoted my question did not understand it exactly. But thanks pablo because you understood it

Answer (score 0):

You can use a compact syntax and modify the subarray elements by reference:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/JoWGd))

```
foreach ($result as &$subarray) {  // & means modify by reference, so you are overwriting the input array, not traversing a copy.
    $subarray['image_url'] = "<img src=\"{$subarray['image_url']}\"/>";
}

var_export($result);
```

There is no need to declare `$key` because the foreach is traversing the actual input array, not a copy of the input array.  The `image_url`s are simply overwritten with each iteration.